# Не собираются модули питон с distutils, получаю error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7

Привет всем!

Установил `Visual Studio 2008`, и при попытке собрать модуль из `C`  выдаёт эту ошибку:

```
D:\DISTUTILS>py setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'ex' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Путь до бинарников visual studio прописал.

Comment: Когда я последний раз собирал модуль (если не находил готового) то пришлось ДОустановить к VS поддержку разработки под с++ и все поехало.

Comment: А по подробнее  ) что нужно доустановить ? и как ?

Comment: Я пишу на VS на шарпе и потому не ставлю поддержку с++ разработки. Запустил инсталлятор, выставил галки для с++ разработки, оно затянуло слишком большую кучу хлама и после этого компиляция модулей стала работать. Теперь сам не собираю, а ищу готовые, благо есть http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: А это да я установил ,  в этом и проблема что питон не находит vcvarsall.bat , смотрел исходники питона но так и не понял как там прописан путь в переменной как то через реестр скрипт сложный ...

Comment: Я для ознакомительных целей , хочу попробовать написать простой модуль, а так в питоне библиотеки на все случаи жизни)

Comment: Не относится напрямую к проблеме, но для  Python 3.5+ следует VS 2015 ставить. [How to deal with the pain of “unable to find vcvarsall.bat”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/)